# addListenerForNotificationOpened is not working in "react-onesignal"

Tags: reactjs, npm, listener, onesignal

I am using React package whose name is *react-onesignal*. I got an issue in the `addListenerForNotificationOpened` event. My code is:

```js
OneSignalReact.addListenerForNotificationOpened((event: any) => {
  if (event.data.type === 'custom_notification') {
    dispatch(alertActions.setDrawerState());
  }
}).catch((errListener) => { console.log('Error One Signal ', errListener); });
```

Though I received the notification when I clicked on it, the event (above mentioned) wasn't triggered. If someone faced this issue before kindly let me know the solution (if any).

Comment: Not supported on Safari and requires HTTPS website.

Are you testing this on your production site on a non-safari browser? Please note that testing this on localhost will not work unless you have set up a secure localhost environment.

I have not been able to reproduce this in a production environment using HTTPS.

Can you please make sure you are testing this in the correct environment?